IOS Device cache clear through automation?
I am performing the localization testing on iOS native app, to verify the new locale and language changes, this operation requires the cache clear in iOS device. I have used

noReset=false

capability to reset the app cache. But still 30% of the locales are not changed in app. currently dev team sharing the builds through testflight app and not sharing the .ipa file directly to use it while creating the appium session. Is there any other way to workaround it through automation?
